# Decorator that adds a keyword parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, decorator

I'm trying to define a decorator that just adds one keyword argument to the decorated function `f`. `f` might have any combination of (positional, keyword, etc) parameters. I tried this:

```py
def capture_wrap(f):
    def captured(name=False, *args, **kwargs):
        """name can be False, True or str. if str, then use it as a name."""
        print (name, f, args, kwargs)
        inner = f(*args, **kwargs)
        if name is False:
            return inner
        elif name is True:
            return capture(inner)
        else:
            return capture(inner, name=name)
    return captured
```

If I try to use it with a function that accepts a single argument:

```py
@capture_wrap
def any_of(s):
    """s must be in the right format.
    See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax ."""
    return wrap('[', Dinant(s, escape=False), ']')
```

```py
0-9A-Fa-f <function any_of at 0x7fb370548a60> () {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./dinant.py", line 222, in <module>
    hex = one_or_more(any_of('0-9A-Fa-f'))
File "./dinant.py", line 116, in captured
    inner = f(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: any_of() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

I get an error because the any argument becomes the `name` parameter in `captured()`. How should I do it correctly?

Comment: Could you explain what "capture()" is and what you really are trying to achieve (=> the problem you're trying to solve with this - currently non working - solution) ?

Comment: Can you please clear what you are passing in s and why do you need it? This will help to give more clear answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make `name` a [keyword-only argument](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) to achieve this. Currently the issue is that it is a positional argument and when you're doing `any_of('foo')` the `'foo'` is being passed to `name` argument.

```
def capture_wrap(f):
    def captured(*args, name=False, **kwargs):
        """name can be False, True or str. if str, then use it as a name."""
        print(name, f, args, kwargs)
        inner = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return captured


@capture_wrap
def any_of(s1, s2, s3, **kwargs):
    return "I do something"
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> any_of('0-9A-Fa-f', 1, 2)
False <function any_of at 0x1041daea0> ('0-9A-Fa-f', 1, 2) {}
'I do something'

>>> any_of('0-9A-Fa-f', 2, 3, a=1, b=2, name='some-name')
some-name <function any_of at 0x1041daea0> ('0-9A-Fa-f', 2, 3) {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
'I do something'
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye They are using print() as function in their code and its output is not a tuple. Also the error message `TypeError: any_of() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'` is Python 3 specific.

Comment: This is how I actually ended up doing it. I simply forgot/didn't know this was valid syntax.

Comment: @MarcosDione It was introduced in Python 3 only.

Comment: Well, at this point, almost 9 years after its release, we should call py3 plain Python, and call py2 "Python legacy" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass name where you are calling the function f
inner = f(name, *args, **kwargs)